# How do I set a a databound dropdown to a dataset value

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down that is bound to a set of values.  When the user selects a value from another drop down the form gets populated. If the value exists in the database I want the value to be already chosen in the drop down. But with the option to choose a new value.

Note the dataset is bound at this point. 
I have tried

```
DataSet dsGetOrders = new DataSet();
foreach (DataRow dsGetOrdersRow in dsGetOrders.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ddpDown.SelectedItem.Text =  dsGetOrdersRow["Vendor_Name"].ToString();
}
```

But this just adds the row in the drop down and doesn't make it the select value.

The drop down `DataTextField` and `DataVaule` are the same field.
I even tried this without success:

```
ddpDown.DataTexField = dsGetOrdersRow["Vendor_Name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in the dropdown data bound event.

Comment: Doing it on data bind would only populate the drop down with the chosen value.   if my drop down has Bob, Bill, Mike and the value in the table is Mike I want Mike selected but the option to pick  the others.

Comment: I found one solution is using ddpDown.SelectedValue =  dsGetOrdersRow["Vendor_Name"].ToString();
This still creates the duplicate row but actually gives the dropdown the proper value so it can be picked up with drpDown.Text